# Not sure why its not binding value

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind value but its not updating with Even and Odd . I am updating num1 and num2 from number box. Thanks

```js
var test = angular.module("test", []);

test.controller("testCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.num1 = 0;
  $scope.num2 = 0;
  $scope.value = ($scope.num1 + $scope.num2) % 2 ? "Even" : "Odd" ;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
  First Number : <input type="number" ng-model="num1"></input>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Second Number : <input type="number" ng-model="num2"></input>
  <br/>
Sum : {{num1 + num2}} is <span>{{value}} </span> <br/>


<br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger it using a function and bind the function

**DEMO**

```js
var test = angular.module("test", []);

test.controller("testCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.num1 = 0;
  $scope.num2 = 0;
  $scope.update = function(){  
     return ($scope.num1 + $scope.num2) % 2 ? "Even" : "Odd" ;
   }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
  First Number : <input type="number" ng-model="num1"/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Second Number : <input type="number" ng-model="num2"/>
  <br/>
Sum : {{num1 + num2}} is <span>{{update()}} </span> <br/>

</body>
</html>
```